# Java 7 JRE Not Detected on Clean Install of Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, java

I know there similar questions on how to enable the Java 7 JRE on Mountain Lion when Apple's Java 6 JRE is installed as well.

But I just did a clean install of Mountain Lion, installed Java 7 JRE - not Java 7 JDK - and it is not being detected.

I see the Java icon in System Preferences. But Java applications are still prompting for a Java 6 installation from Mountain Lion. And running "**java -version**" from the command line also does the same.

Oracle's instructions seem to say that I do not need to do anything further then simply installing the JRE. And online tutorials I read also suggest the same.

Does anyone have an idea why this is?

Comment: Good question! I just faced the same issue with a fresh Lion + JRE7. Thanks! +1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In [Oracle's JRE 7 for Mac installation instructions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/mac/mac-jre.html#requirements), it states:

> Installing a JRE from Oracle will not:
>
> - Update java -version symlinks or add java to your path.
> - Show the installed JRE in the Java Preferences.app
>
> To be able to do the above, 
>    you need to install the JDK.

After [installing the JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7u7-downloads-1836413.html), go to Applications > Utilities > Java Preferences.app and drag Java SE 7 to the top to indicate that it is preferred.  You may also switch off Java SE 6 entirely without uninstalling it.

Comment: Unbelievable that I missed that! I installed JDK and it worked. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score -2):

Uninstall java by revo and go to control panal and java and settings and deleted files. then click ok.and restart computer then install java again from java.com

Comment: Java is not installed (well /usr/bin/java) is not - the one the OP installed is just for Java applets